# How to call a non-static method from another class without using instances in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I know that this question had already been asked, but those answers didn't quite satisfy. I am writing a wpf application in c# for connecting to a usb device. My non-static class Connections has all the meth for connecting, disconnecting and so on. Since i'm using databinding, Icommand and so on, i have to access that class from a lot of other classes. Making my class static is not an option, because it would need to change too much code, and using instatces is not an option too, because i may be calling an instance of a class, but the original doesn't change, so the objects, that are bound to that class don't change too.

So my question is: how do i access my Connections class from other classes?

Comment: That's not how it works. You can't.

Comment: You need to rethink your code architecture, something is clearly wrong here. Refactoring is not a bad thing, ruling out a rewrite because it is too much effort is the wrong mindset.

Comment: Take a look at MVVM pattern. Your connection Model is wired to the View via ViewModel (where you have all logic to handle diconnected case, bindings, user interactions, etc.). That would fix your issue with databindings (ViewModel properties are used for bindings and expose commands) and you are free to make it static (or simply store instance somewhere and access it, e.g. singleton or some manager class).

Comment: You can call methods without an instance e.g. Connections(null).connect() within the method you can check if (this == null) but I really do not recommend that solution.  Note that the methods cannot be virtual nor abstract and it is a real mess that you will regret ever after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends on the functionality of your Connections class.

The easiest answer I can give is that you can make the individual methods static, assuming they don't require instance specific data.

If your individual methods require instance specific data, then you could possibly make the instance a singleton instance (either through have an Instance readonly property, or configuring an IOC container). The singleton works if everyone in the memory context will be using the same instance.

If different instances are needed, but need to be shared across some items, then you can look at structuring your code as having a parent ViewModel that contains the instance that the children ViewModels care about. The children would then have a reference to the parent ViewModel.

Answer (score 4):

You have to pick: *either* you create an instance, *or* you use static methods. Period.

I would recommend to use pass along the instance (possibly exposed through an interface) to the view model or other code you need it in. There you call the methods on the passed-in instance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static wrapper class that instantiates a singleton of the class you're interested in then you can access methods and properties through that.